# How to completely reset Gnome and desktop tweaks on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: gnome, 15.04, themes, ubuntu-gnome, ubuntu-tweak

I have been tweaking too much my Gnome Desktop and it became bogus. It appears many unpleasant visual details that makes the use boring.

I have tweak many things like main menu background color, various themes and tweaked the windows managers Compiz and Metacity.

How can I reset everything from window appearance to desktop tweaks?

I am using currently Gnome Shell and can be noticed in the printscreen the edges of the window are weird and the background of it.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does resetting Gnome tweak tool's settings help?

[image]